# GitLab API: Number of pending builds

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

**Question**: I'm trying to figure out how to get the number of pending jobs/builds/pipelines from the GitLab API.

**Background**: The goal is to use this data as the base for auto-scaling the CI runners based on pending buils. Due to the spiky nature of our jobs regular CPU-based autoscaling doesn't work well. The jobs finish too fast and the runners take too long to start up.

**What I've done**: I've looked at the [Pipelines API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/pipelines.html) as well as the [Jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html). We're polling all jobs with `Scope` `pending` and all Pipelines with `Status` `pending`, but these are always zero. Even if there are pending builds.

TBH I'm not even sure about the terminology here. Should I be looking at the Jobs API, the Pipelines API or something else altogether?

Also I'm not sure about the meaning of `Scope` vs. `Status` here. Unfortunately it isn't explained in the API docs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the list of pending jobs from [Jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/jobs.html#list-project-jobs):

```
curl -g --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_private_token>" "https://<gitlab_url>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs?scope=pending"
```

**Example:** I start a pipeline where is `9` jobs, but the `concurrency` on my runner is set to `3` :

```
curl -g --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_private_token>" "https://<gitlab_url>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs?scope=pending" | jq '. | length'
```

And output is correctly `6`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I did that before, but my code had some unrelated bugs. After fixing them this worked as intended. Thanks!